# INSERT statement with TABLOCK hint can be minimum logged under full recovery mode in SQL Server 2014, why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-administration

From Microsoft [Understanding Minimally Logged Operations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx)

> Minimally logged operations are available only if your database is in bulk-logged or simple recovery mode.

The code below explains what I saw.

```
use master;

IF DB_ID('RecoveryETL') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE RecoveryETL SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 
    DROP DATABASE RecoveryETL;
END

--Create sample database for testing
CREATE DATABASE RecoveryETL 
ON PRIMARY
    (NAME = N'RecoveryETL_Date', FILENAME = N'C:\SQLDATA\RecoveryETL_Data.Mdf', SIZE = 1024MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 50MB)
LOG ON
    (NAME = N'RecoveryETL_Log', FILENAME = N'C:\SQLDATA\RecoveryETL_Log.LDF', SIZE = 100MB, MAXSIZE = 1024MB, FILEGROWTH = 25MB)
GO

--Set Recovery Mode to Full
ALTER DATABASE RecoveryETL SET RECOVERY FULL ;
GO

USE RecoveryETL;
GO

--Immediately perform a full backup otherwise database will remain in simple mode
BACKUP DATABASE RecoveryETL
TO DISK = 'C:\Database Backups\RecoveryETL_1.bak'
WITH RETAINDAYS = 90 
, FORMAT
, INIT
, MEDIANAME = 'RecoveryETL'
, NAME = 'RecoveryETL-Full Database Backup'
, COMPRESSION ;
GO

--Create a Testing Table
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.HeapTable') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.HeapTable

CREATE TABLE HeapTable
(
    Fld1 INT, 
    Fld2 INT, 
    FId3 INT,
    ModDate Datetime
)

--Insert Records W/O TABLOCK hint
INSERT INTO HeapTable (Fld1, Fld2, FId3, ModDate)
    SELECT TOP 10000 
        SalesOrderDetailID, SalesOrderDetailID + 100, SalesOrderDetailID + 99, GETDATE()
    FROM 
        AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail

--Is it minimum logged? No, more than 10,000 log records
SELECT * 
FROM sys.fn_dblog(null, null)
WHERE AllocUnitName LIKE '%HeapTable%' 

--Truncate logs
CHECKPOINT;

BACKUP LOG RecoveryETL
TO DISK = 'NULL'
WITH RETAINDAYS = 90
, NOINIT
, MEDIANAME = 'RecoveryETL'
, NAME = 'RecoveryETL-Log Backup'
, COMPRESSION ;
GO

--Make sure logs are gone
SELECT * 
FROM sys.fn_dblog(null, null)
WHERE AllocUnitName LIKE '%HeapTable%' 

--Insert records WITH TABLOCK hint
INSERT INTO HeapTable WITH(TABLOCK)(Fld1, Fld2, FId3, ModDate)
    SELECT TOP 10000 
        SalesOrderDetailID, SalesOrderDetailID + 100, SalesOrderDetailID + 99, GETDATE()
    FROM 
        AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail

--Minimum logged here!!!!!
SELECT * 
FROM sys.fn_dblog(null, null)
WHERE AllocUnitName LIKE '%HeapTable%'
```

I was also trying to restore database point-in-time using the log backup with minimum logged logs, as expected I was not able to bring database out of restoring state, where I can say they are truly minimum logged. The official documentation is inaccurate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where I can say they are truly minimum logged. The official
>   documentation is inaccurate?

No, you are wrong.

Yes there were changes in how `INSERT`s are fully logged, but under `full recovery model` even with `TABLOCK` they are still f**ully logged**.

In `SQL SERVER 2005`-`2008` `INSERT` under `full recovery model` was logged row by row, so if you made 10000 rows `INSERT` in the log file you saw at least 10000 `LOP_INSERT_ROW` operations (see my first pictur)

[image]

Now I made the same `INSERT` on `SQL SERVER 2016` first under `BULK_LOGGED` recovery model and then under the `FULL` (you can see the result on my second picture). Under `BULK_LOGGED` you can see that only bitmap settings were logged, so operation is really `minimally logged`. but under FULL recovery moder the picture is different. Yes you don't see 10000 `LOP_INSERT_ROW` rows anymore but now you can see 38 `LOP_FORMAT_PAGE` operations, eand very log row corresponding to this operetion is of `8276` bytes, i.e. `8Kb`, one `page`. These 38 pages are full page images that were formatted during the `INSERT`, as it was done even in 2008 for `INDEX REBUILD` operations. So the operation is still `fully logged`, the info that goes into the log is enough to completely reconstitute operation, not only to permit the rollback as in case of `minimally logged` operations. So `INSERT` into a heap even with `TABLOCK` hint is still **fully logged** operation but now it's even **efficiently logged** operation. I tried even to backup log after my INSERT under the `FULL` and I was able to restore from this log with `stop at` at the time prior to backup log was finished.

[image]

Comment: Thank for the answer sepupic, that is helpful!